# Missing font on compile

Tags: fonts, tex-core

I have been given a latex template to use for my school thesis, however when I try to compile the demo to pdf:

```
pdflatex thesis.tex
```

I get the following error:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 0+540/600 --dpi 540 eurmo10
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for eurmo10.
```

I have looked in my text font folder and the font does 'exist'

```
ls /usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/tfm/adobe/palatino | grep eurmo
```

Giving,

```
eurmo10.tfm
```

From some googling, I tried using `udpmap` and `udpmap-sys`, but these did not help:

```
 updmap --enable Map eurmo10

!!! ERROR! The map file `eurmo10' has not been found at all.
```

Can someone please point me in the direction on how to fix this error so I can compile the `tex` file?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show us the template?

Comment: Thanks canaaerus, the template and 'guide' are here: http://cs.anu.edu.au/study/currentstudents/honours/resources

Comment: I take it, that you have followed all the installation instruction precisely!? In particular having `texlive-fonts-recommended` installed and running `texhash`.

Comment: I have, two different times.

Comment: The error message means that the map-file has not been activated. So `updmap` is the right way to go. But `eurmo10.map` is not the name of a map (also I'm not sure if TeXLive accept a map name without extension). Try in your document `\pdfmapfile{=mathpple.map}`. If is works enable `mathpple.map` with updmap.

Comment: I get the error: `!!! ERROR! The map file 'eurmo10' has not been found at all.` Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: @Neutros As Ulrike said, you have to use the name `mathpple.map` and *not* `eurmo10.map`. Don't use `updmap` if you can use `updmap-sys` with administrator privileges.

Comment: Using the command: `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map mathpple.map` I get the same error as per above: `!!! ERROR! The map file 'eurmo10' has not been found at all.`

Comment: Well you obviously added somehow eurmo10.map to some configuration file. So disable it again. Also as you already used `updmap` and so generated local file `updmap-sys` will no longer work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The font `eurmo10` is defined in the map file `mathpple.map`:

```
% $Id: mathpple.map 20947 2011-01-06 00:27:02Z karl $
% Thomas Esser, 2002, public domain.
%
% These fonts are only available as type 1, so we
% separate them from the other bluesky fonts.
eurbo10 EURB10 ".167 SlantFont" <eurb10.pfb
eurmo10 EURM10 ".167 SlantFont" <eurm10.pfb
```

I found the file in (TeX Live 2011):

```
texmf/fonts/map/dvips/tetex/mathpple.map
```

It is unclear to me, why it is not in `texmf-dist`.

The command line for `updmap` would be:

```
updmap --enable Map mathpple.map
```

If you want to test first, in pdfTeX map files can also be added at TeX macro level,
e.g. at the top of the TeX file:

```
\pdfmapfile{+mathpple.map}
```

For `dvips` map files can be specified on the command line:

```
dvips -u mathpple.map test.dvi
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however after running the command I get: `updmap: Scanning for Map entries:
updmap: using map file `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/dvips/psnfss/charter.map'
updmap: using map file `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/dvips/chemarrow/chemarrow.map'
updmap: using map file `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/dvips/epiolmec/epiolmec.map'
updmap: using map file `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/dvips/amsfonts/euler.map'

!!! ERROR! The map file `eurmo10' has not been found at al`

Comment: One can also say `\pdfmapline{+eurmo10 EURM10 ".167 SlantFont" <eurm10.pfb}`